# Remove page margins fill entire page for print

Tags: printing, gimp

I'm trying to print a image that I created using GIMP (A4 size) but there's a margin in page that cuts out part of image.

It's a Epson L-210 printer.

print settings and print preview:
[image: GIMP Print, Image Settings tag]
[image: Epson Print Settings tab 1]
[image: Epson Print Settings tab 2]
[image: Print Preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the L-210 printer does not support boarder-less printing, according to Epson's [Singapore site](http://www.epson.com.sg/sites/epson_singapore/L-Series_FAQ/L-Series_FAQ.page). Your only solution would be to use a printer that does support boarder-less printing.